# Empirical Risk Equal to True Error under condition

Tags: machine-learning, error

[Note: Crosspost from stackoverflow, I think I maybe should've started here]

I've been working through "Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms", and on pg. 46, after the realizability assumption has been dropped from the defintions of loss/risk "L", a note is made that:

[image: eq]

where D is an arbitrary joint probability distribution X x Y, X is the feature set, Y is the label set, S is a sample (sampled from the distribution D) of size m, and h is a learned hypothesis.

However, I don't understand this notation - what does it mean to have a probability distribution "uniform over S"? Does this mean that, whatever the distribution D is, that S is sampled uniformly over it according to the probabilities (over the valid domain) defined in D? What happens when the data size m isn't nearly large enough to encapsulate some notion of "uniform"?

Comment: By definition, a uniform distribution assigns the same probability (or density) to everything, as appropriate.  That works even for a sample of size one.  Absent an explanation of the symbols you are using (what are "X", "Y", "L", and "h", and what is 
"S" sampling?), I can only guess what might be intended.  Others without access to the book are likely in the same situation.

Comment: I've made the clarifications needed. However, D is expressly not a uniform distribution - this is where I'm getting confused, because what is "sampling uniformly" over an arbitrary distribution? Or is this the correct reading at all?

Comment: As I wrote, I can only guess; but I would take the right hand side just to be a fancy way of saying you compute the arithmetic mean of the loss of $h$ over all the elements of the sample.

Comment: In the [copy I found online](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/w~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/copy.html), the answer to your question is explicitly given immediately above the line you quote on p. 46: it writes out the formula for the arithmetic mean of the loss.

Comment: Right, I saw the definition of empirical loss - however, what does the note (given in the LaTex in the question) mean? Or rather, what's the logic behind the equality under the "uniform over S" condition?

Comment: That's just notation, nothing else.  It is *specifying* that the arithmetic mean is the same thing as the expected loss for the empirical distribution function (the uniform distribution over the data).

Comment: Oh, I see - thanks! I'll answer the question, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As whuber discusses in his comments, this is simply notation to denote that the empirical loss $L_S(h) = \frac{1}{m} \sum_i 1_{h(x_i) \neq f(x_i)}$ is the same as the expected value of the true loss, that is: $L_S(h) = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_S[L_{D (\text{uniform over S)}}(h)]$.